# Looking for a right regEx (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a right regex that would match "/anyword/" and perhaps "/ln/anyword/" in both:

http://localhost:3000/anyword

https://www.somedomain/ln/anyword

The "ln" in the second domain can be any two letter. (As languages).

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: /\/anyword(?=$)/gi;

/\/anyword/gi;

Comment: it seems to be working https://regex101.com/r/MGhFw1/1/, what is wrong?

Comment: Make sure to use `gim` not `gi` to match the beginning and end of each line

Comment: @mrzasa I think he means he wants any word, and not the string "anyword"

Comment: So we have one `downvoter`! I almost thought there will be none...

Comment: @mrzasa, thanks, man. Sorry, I forgot to mention javascript... anyway, the solution didn't match the `/ln/` part

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\w)(/.+)` See https://regex101.com/r/3Ahynm/2

The capture group contains the desired text

Answer (score 0):

What work as the above answer suggested:

```
/(?:\w)(\/.+)/i
```